# Speed up date columns conversion (pandas) from string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, runtime, date-parsing

I am working with a large .csv file in python and its date column is 'str'.
I am using the following code to convert the records in this column to datetime.

```
df[date_column].fillna('1900-01-01',inplace=True)
df[date_column] = df[date_column].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x, format = datetime_format))
```

But this seems to be taking quite a long time to execute. Any suggestions on how to handle this is welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read your csv , you can using `parse_dates`

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourcsv.csv',parse_dates = date_column)
```

Then let us using `converters`

```
pd.read_csv('yourcsv.csv', converters={'date_column':lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x,errors = 'coerce')})
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but since there are NULLS, it is not working as it should.

Comment: @Dtengu have you try `converters`

Comment: Good suggestion, takes less time. I also found something interesting over here that works much faster: https://github.com/sanand0/benchmarks/tree/master/date-parse