# Fetch datetime from strings faster from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, optimization

Extract day,month,year,hour,weekday,day_month_year from the data and put then in columns

Data columns :

```
+----------------------+
|         Date         |
+----------------------+
| '11/28/17  00:36 '   |
| '11/28/17  01:15 AM' |
| 'abc'                |
| 11/28/17  01:28 '    |
| 'pqr'                |
+----------------------+
```

Target:

```
+-----+-------+------+---------+------+-----------------+
| Day | Month | Year | Weekday | Hour | Day_month_year  |
+-----+-------+------+---------+------+-----------------+
| 28  | Nov   | 2017 | Tue     | 00   | 2017-11-28      |
| 28  | Nov   | 2017 | Tue     | 01   | 2017-11-28      |
| Nan | Nan   | Nan  | Nan     | Nan  | Nan             |
| 28  | Nov   | 2017 | Tue     | 01   | 2017-11-28      |
| Nan | Nan   | Nan  | Nan     | Nan  | Nan             |
+-----+-------+------+---------+------+-----------------+
```

Code:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True,errors='coerce')
df['Day'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%d')
df['Month'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%b')
df['Year'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y')
df['WeekDay'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%a')
df['Hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H')
df['Day_month_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.to_period('D')
```

These lines of code takes long time as my Date column doesn't have a particular data format and has few values which can't be parsed as datetime. Is there a faster way to perform this operation as my Date columns have almost 40k records.

Comment: Try converting to datetime when you initialize the dataframe.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392909/speed-up-date-columns-conversion-pandas-from-string-to-datetime

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df['Day'] = s.dt.day
df['Month'] = s.dt.month
df['Year'] = s.dt.year
df['Weekday'] = s.dt.strftime('%a')
df['Hour'] = s.dt.hour
df['Day_Month_Year'] = s.dt.date
```

Output:

```
                 Date   Day  Month    Year Weekday  Hour Day_Month_Year
0    11/28/17  00:36   28.0   11.0  2017.0     Tue   0.0     2017-11-28
1  11/28/17  01:15 AM  28.0   11.0  2017.0     Tue   1.0     2017-11-28
2                 abc   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaT   NaN            NaT
3    11/28/17  01:28   28.0   11.0  2017.0     Tue   1.0     2017-11-28
4                 pqr   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaT   NaN            NaT
```

The columns are converted to floats because they have to deal with `NaN`. They are easy enough to convert to `int`.